# How to change newline button to space to finish reading from input stream?

Tags: c++, c

I need to read a row of symbols from input stream without going to new line after reading each symbol. More precisely, I need to change hitting the "Enter" button to "Space" after reading each new symbol. Is there a way to do it without reading all row to a string and parsing string after that? Any options are acceptable, like scanf, cin.

Comment: So the user would never hit the Enter button?

Comment: the terminal driver does not pass the keystrokes to a program (in 'cooked' mode) until the <enter> key is pressed.   However in 'raw' mode, each keystroke is immediately passed to the program.   The program will see two bytes for each keystroke (the upper byte contains info about shift keys, etc)  The program will have to handle backspace, etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use conio.h then you can do that by reading input in a character array with getch() function. Or if you are in visual studio you can use _getch() function for the same result.

conio.h defines function named getch() and getche() which reads a character then terminates without any enter key. Both these functions have specific meanings while they do the same task. I don't use those any more so I don't remember much. It's upto you if you wanna use them or not...

Answer (score 0):

> ### Entering input seperated by <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> are equivalent.

But, you do need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> **at the end** of your space seperated input, because that is the default for `stdin` in C/C++.

If your program is something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[5];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
}
```

and you input:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

This would be similar to:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

But you do need to hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key at the end for the program to accept your input for five variables **as a whole**.

If you are talking about *never pressing an <kbd>Enter</kbd> key*,

## It is impossible.

Until you are reading input from a file, of course.